# Microsoft graph .Net error OAuth2 in windows server to access mailbox - WINHTTP_CALLBACK_STATUS_REQUEST_ERROR

Tags: .net, api, graph, oauth-2.0

I have an application using microsoft graph to access mailbox. it works on dev machine with windows 10.
In the server, i am getting the error given below. (windows server 2016 and windows server 2012)

**"System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.Http.WinHttpException: Error 12002 calling WINHTTP_CALLBACK_STATUS_REQUEST_ERROR, 'The operation timed out'."**

detailed error

Status Code: 0
Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: Code: generalException
Message: An error occurred sending the request.
---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.Http.WinHttpException: Error 12002 calling WINHTTP_CALLBACK_STATUS_REQUEST_ERROR, 'The operation timed out'.
at System.Threading.Tasks.RendezvousAwaitable`1.GetResult() at System.Net.Http.WinHttpHandler.<StartRequestAsync>d_122.MoveNext() --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Microsoft.Graph.RedirectHandler.<SendAsync>d6.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Microsoft.Graph.RetryHandler.<SendAsync>d9.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Microsoft.Graph.CompressionHandler.<SendAsync>d2.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Microsoft.Graph.AuthenticationHandler.<SendAsync>d16.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Microsoft.Graph.HttpProvider.<SendRequestAsync>d19.MoveNext() --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at Microsoft.Graph.HttpProvider.<SendRequestAsync>d19.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Microsoft.Graph.HttpProvider.<SendAsync>d18.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Microsoft.Graph.BaseRequest.<SendRequestAsync>d40.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Microsoft.Graph.BaseRequest.<SendAsync>d34`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.Graph.MailFolderMessagesCollectionRequest.d_3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()

Comment: Please indicate which version of .Net or .net core you are using, which runtimes / SDK are installed on your machine and on the server, and what kind of application it is (console, web, wpf...)

Comment: i am using .Net 4.7.2 framework. The same is installed on both windows 10 and windows server machines. i am using basic console application to check the mailbox and display the subject

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been tracking down the exact same issue and have found that our machine had a proxy configured using netsh and the proxy server wasn't available. So the "operation timeout" was 100% valid.

You can check by calling "netsh winhttp show proxy" from a command prompt. Our proxy was from an older test scenario and so we just cleared it with "netsh winhttp reset proxy" from an admin command prompt.

I think this only broke on our server after upgrading the Microsoft.Graph nuget package. Maybe it has been "improved" it to follow the system-wide proxy server configuration.

This also explains why I couldn't get Fiddler tracing working for the Graph API calls, but it was working for the MSAL authentication calls.